# Laravel:Failed to load resource

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hey i am new at laravel and i am making an autocomplete search bar. But i am having problem that is when i write any word it gives error in my console panel that is

```
     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
```

Controller of my code is given below

```
     <?php
      namespace App\Http\Controllers;


      use Illuminate\Http\Request;
      use App\Disease;
      use Input;

    class DiseaseController extends Controller
      {
       public function index()
      {
            return view('disease.disease');
       }
     public function autocomplete(Request $request)
     {
        $term = $request->term;
          $data = Disease::where('symtomps','Like','%'.$term.'%')
        ->take(2)
        ->get();
        $result=array();

      foreach($data as $key => $v)
    {
        $results[]=['id' =>$v->id,'value'=>$v->symtomps];
    }
    return response()->json($results);
    }
 }
```

View of my code is

```
              <html>
       <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
            beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
  <body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col col-md-4">
      <section class="card">
         <header class="card-heading">
             <input type="text" name="searchname" class="form-control" id="searchname" placeholder="Search"  >
          </header>
          <div class="card-block">
            <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>ID</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="id" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Symtomps</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="symtomps" class="form-control" ></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

          </div>
       </section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$('#searchname').autocomplete({
    source: '{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',
    minlength:1,
    autoFocus:true,
    select:function(e,ui){
    $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
}
});

</script>
```

And route is

```
Route::get('/',array('as'=>'disease','uses'=>'DiseaseController@index'));
  Route::get('/autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete',
  'uses'=>'DiseaseController@autocomplete'));
```

Please help me where i am doing wrong as its not showing me any data when i type any word it just show the error in the console.

Comment: Open source html and see what path is in `source: '{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',`

Comment: @u_mulder can u please tell me where to find source html

Comment: In a context menu of your browser.

Comment: @u_mulder in my console panel with the error the path which is coming ig /TestProject/public/autocomplete?term=te

Comment: change url {{!! !!}} we r not using this for routes this is mostly used for diaplaying data..try using routes with {{ }}.then i think ur route works fine

Comment: @RamAnji no its not working its giving syntax error if i change